# Will 2008 Chevy HHR Winter Rims fit a 2017 Chevy Cruze?

Tags: wheels, winter, swap

I'm sure these measurements are obvious, but I don't know what they mean:

HHR:

– Center Bore: 65.1 mm
– PCD: 5x110

Cruze:

– Center Bore: 56.6 mm
– PCD: 5x105

Answer (score 2):

No, they won't fit.

The bore is too large so the wheels will not centre properly.

The lug holes are on a different circle diameter so the wheels won't even go on for the bore hole to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

PCD stands for Pitch Circle Diameter. That's the circle that the 5 studs describe. Each hole is on the circumference of circle with that diameter. So, the ' 5' means 5 studs, but the circle that each wheel has holes in is different by 5mm - near 1/4". With a bit of judicious filing, they may slip on - but DON'T TRY IT !

The other problem is the big hole in the wheel's centre is too big to go over the hub, as in it would flop about, making it difficult to centre the wheel when fitting.

Another problem *may* be that the 'countersink taper' for the wheel nuts or bolts may also be different, so they won't seat properly..